# Generating dialog from a separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

I have almost completed converting a pyGTK application to pyQT4.
One of the last aspects I am struggling with is generating a dialog from a separate thread.

I have a main GUI and a background thread. On the offchance of thread-specific issues, the thread generates a dialog.

For pyGTK what I do is:

```
  def update_gui(function, *args, **kargs):
      '''DocString'''
      def idle_func():
          '''DocString'''
          Gdk.threads_enter()
          try:
            function(*args, **kargs)
          finally:
              Gdk.threads_leave()
      GObject.idle_add(idle_func)


  def gui_error(msg):
      '''Simple wrapper for a warning dialog'''
      md = Gtk.MessageDialog(parent=None, message_type=Gtk.MessageType.WARNING, buttons=Gtk.ButtonsType.CLOSE)
      md.set_markup(msg)
      md.run()
      md.destroy()
```

Called as: update_gui(gui_error,'help')

Is there an equivelent in pyQT4 or do I need to gut what I have to start passing signals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *do I need to gut what I have to start passing signals?*

yes you do.

You can always have your "other thread" be `QObject` based and have a `QObject` from `QApplication`'s children based object as parent, and call the `moveToThread()` method but it's better to have the main thread handle GUI, and other threads send signals to the main thread to have it updated.

Take the opportunity of moving from GTK to QT, to actually redesign correctly your application, with real decoupling between the main components of your software.

Comment: Thats what I feared... It was relatively painless to convert threading.Thread to QtCore.QThread and "emit" a few signals. One final Query: almost all of these are warning dialogs. What would be a good way to then make use of a dialog with a ok/cancel response needing to be fed back to a worker thread?

Comment: actually, the whole signaling model of Qt is pretty painless, and can help make a code coming from Gtk a lot more readable. Think of building independant blocks, to correctly advertise your signals, and connect your slots for working out the public interfaces between the components of your graphical application. No more spaghetti code!